# django ModelForm - override save() and add fields to self._meta.fields

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I'm trying to override `save()` method of a `ModelForm`. I have to add some fields to `self._meta.fields` (i have to do not include them in the `Meta` class fields for some reasons), here's the code:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    """
    Save override
    """
    fields_to_save_list = list(self._meta.fields)
    fields_to_save_list.extend(['city','region','zip'])
    fields_to_save_tuple = tuple(fields_to_save_list)
    setattr(self._meta, 'fields', fields_to_save_tuple)
    return super(SubjectAdminForm, self).save(commit)
```

It doesn't work, my self._meta.fields are always the same. Maybe some basic python mistake. any help?

Answer (score 1):

This wont work. You need to add it in the `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PartialAuthorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['city'] = forms.CharField()    
    self.fields['region'] = forms.CharField()
    self.fields['zip'] = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: already done. i dont want to show the initial values for these fields cause i have duplicate widget for the same three fields (the duplicates are 'city_sel','region_sel','zip_sel', they are select widgets and are only forms field, instead of 'city','region','zip' are also model fields). respective widget are showen/hidden by a js,  depending on selected country (I have a select widget for countries). it works but it doesn't save values, since in save_instance method of parent save() is callled a construct_instance method, which loops on fields declared on Meta. How i can add values to Meta?

Comment: it is not because fields are not in meta, but may be you are using a modelfield, and model doesnt have those fields. I believe you should not do it in save method though

Comment: is it possible to dinamically add those fields and where?

Comment: well, in the init, you are essentially adding it at runtime.